# logstash create new file every 30seconds

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I have following filter configuration in my logstatsh pipeline. What it does is, at the start of the event first filter creates a CSV file with header and sets the file name to metadata. Second filter writes the output to above CSV.

The challenge (or) requirement I have is:Every Xseconds, we need to create new CSV file and write to that file. I am not ruby expert and couldn't get any clues from Google search. Can someone please advise?

```
  filter {
    ruby {
       init => "
            begin
                randval = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join      
                @csv_file = 'output'+randval+'.csv'
                csv_headers = ['YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ','Log Level','Event ID']
                if File.zero?(@csv_file) || !File.exist?(@csv_file)
                    CSV.open(@csv_file, 'w') do |csv|
                        csv << csv_headers
                    end
                    
                end
            end
        "
        code => '
                event.set("[@metadata][suffix]",@csv_file)
        '
    }
}


output {
   file {
      path => "output.log"
   }    
   csv {
       fields => [ "created", "level", "code"]
       path => "%{[@metadata][suffix]}"
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe instead of random numbers use the current time and divide by 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough, someone asked exactly this question at [discuss.elastic.co](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/create-new-file-every-60seconds-in-logstash-csv-output/299380) yesterday, complete with the same unnecessary init option, so I happen to know that the answer is

```
ruby {
    code => '
            event.set("[@metadata][suffix]", 'output' + (Time.now.to_i / 30).to_s + '.csv')
    '
}
```

This will result in the file output writing to a different file for any events that arrive in a 30 second interval.

I am not aware of any way to add a header just for the first event written to the file by an output. A csv output can add headers for every row. A csv codec can write headers once, but would not write them again when the file name changed.

That said, if you are just writing to a file you could do the write in the ruby filter and keep track of whether a header has been written for the current value of Time.now.to_i / 30. You could do that using something similar to this. I re-purposed some of the code from the [csv output](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-csv/tree/main/lib/logstash/outputs).

```
input { heartbeat { interval => 5 message => '{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 }' } }
filter {
    json { source => "message" target => "data" remove_field => [ "message" ] }
    ruby {
        init => '
            @fields = [ "[data][bar]", "[data][baz]" ]
            @csv_options = Hash.new
            @spreadsheet_safe = true
        '
        code => '
            def event_to_csv(event)
                csv_values = @fields.map {|name| get_value(name, event)}
                csv_values.to_csv(@csv_options)
            end

            def get_value(name, event)
                val = event.get(name)
                val.is_a?(Hash) ? LogStash::Json.dump(val) : escape_csv(val)
            end

            def escape_csv(val)
                (@spreadsheet_safe && val.is_a?(String) && val.start_with?("=")) ? "\'#{val}" : val
            end

            id = Time.now.to_i / 20
            file = "output" + id.to_s + ".csv"

            fd = open("/tmp/#{file}", "a")
            if id != @last_id
                chunk = "bar,baz\n"
                fd.write(chunk)
            end

            chunk = event_to_csv(event)
            fd.write(chunk)
            fd.close

            @last_id = id
            event.cancel
        '
    }
}
```

Comment: That was me and I was expecting you (I see your id as very active id) or someone could provide guidance. 1) The reason for using "init" was, I need "header" in the file and seems only way to get the header inserted is using "init" option, please correct me if I am wrong.  2) Would this answer creates file every 30 seconds (or) writes file on every event receipt? If you don't mind, could you please help me with some explanation so I can understand what I am dealing with? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I updated to try to address that.

Comment: Thank you! Right now I am using CSV codec because we have another downstream service which understands only CSV format.  Is there any reference available for me to experiment with "ruby filter based file creation" instead of "CSV codec"? I would like to try this approach and create CSV if possible. Sorry for these basic questions, I have ZERO experience with ruby code. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Updated again to include ruby example.

Comment: Can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71548974/logstash-file-output-not-working-with-metadata-fileds