# logstash file output not working with metadata fileds

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I have following pipeline, the requirement is, I need to write "metrics" data to ONE file and EVENT data to another file. I am having two issues with this pipeline.

1. The file output not creating a "timestamped file" every 30 seconds, instead it is creating a file with this name `output%{[@metadata][ts]}.csv` and keep on appending the data.
2. The CSV output, creating a new file with timestamp every 30 seconds, but somehow it is creating an extra file once with the name `output%{[@metadata][ts]}` and keep on appending meta info to this file.

Can someone please guide me how I can fix this?

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5045
  }
}

filter {
   ruby {
        code => '
                event.set("[@metadata][ts]",  Time.now.to_i / 30)
                event.set("[@metadata][suffix]", "output" + (Time.now.to_i / 30).to_s + ".csv")
        '
    }
}

filter {
  metrics {
    meter => [ "code" ]
    add_tag => "metric"
    clear_interval => 30
    flush_interval => 30
  }
}


output {

    if "metric" in [tags] {
        file {
            flush_interval => 30
            codec => line { format => "%{[code][count]} %{[code][count]}"}
            path => "C:/lgstshop/local/csv/output%{[@metadata][ts]}.csv"
        }
        stdout {
          codec => line {
            format => "rate: %{[code][count]}"
          }
        }
      }

   file {
      path => "output.log"
   }    
   csv {
       fields => [ "created", "level", "code"]
       path => "C:/lgstshop/local/output%{[@metadata][ts]}.evt"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A metrics filter generates new events in the pipeline. Those events will only go through filters that come after it. Thus the metric events do not have a [@metadata][ts] field, so the sprintf references in the output section are not substituted. Move the ruby filter so that it is after the metrics filter.

If you do not want the metrics sent to the csv then wrap that output with `if "metric" not in [tags] {` or put it in an else of the existing conditional.

Comment: Ah, will try it in an hour and let you know. Thanks for quick guidance!

Comment: Any suggestions on second issue?

Comment: Seems this metric filter appending few rows to CSV output with metric information, is there anyway to not do that?@Badger

Comment: Update about csv output.

Comment: if you have few mins, here is one more thing I need help with. I am no more using metric filter due to few customizations we need, instead went with "ruby" filter which is helping me with larger control.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563167/logstash-grok-pattern-to-extract-china-text